# navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package (expo)

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, expo

since the last update my expo project always generates the error: navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components' instead of 'react-native'. Learn about alternative navigation solutions at [...].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZFvj.jpg)
But when i try to import it from the new package i get the error: the development server returned response errror code: 500 [...].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqTYl.jpg)

I work with expo and the following code. The error however accurs in every new project i want to create with expo. Old project still work. When i copy the old code in my new projects i got the same error as. 
I think that the code is functional and the problem is in the package manager for example.

```html
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import {Navigator} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import {Text, View, /*Navigator*/} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
    super()

   // this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this) /* bindet die funktion renderScene an das aktuelle this objekt*/
   }

   renderScene(route, navigator){
    if(route.name === 'WelcomePage'){
     return <WelcomePage navigator={navigator}/>
    }
    else if(route.name === 'PlayerSelect'){
        return <PlayerSelect navigator={navigator}/>
    }
   }








    render() {
      return (
        <View>
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{name: 'WelcomePage'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          />

          <Text> Hallo</Text>
         </View>
      );
    }
    }

Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

What i have to do to make my code work again? 
Thanks in advance,

Maffinius

Comment: for new projects I would use react-navigation: https://reactnavigation.org

Comment: Edit: The Expo Interface outputs the Error: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
15:07:09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should import and use it like following:

```
import CustomComponents from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';

<CustomComponents.Navigator
  initialRoute={{name: 'WelcomePage'}}
  renderScene={this.renderScene}
/>
```

Comment: Consider you might need to install the package:  npm i react-native-deprecated-custom-components

Answer (score -1):

I got a link which solve my same error so i guess here will work too.
http://www.hongming.me/?p=670